# "Containing" or "consisting of"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs

My memory is shocking lately and would like your advice on choosing a word. See, I am building an app for a client, and there's a notification area that says (or will say), something like this:

> New Order containing 6 items.

But then I thought, should I replace "containing" with "consisting of"? So it reads:

> New Order consisting of 6 items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of those are correct. I would stick with "containing" since it's shorter.

Comment: Shorter? They both have 10 characters lol.

Comment: Lol? "Consisting of" has 13 characters roflmao.

Comment: Actually 12 characters, :)

Comment: Count words and syllables. Characters are for nerds.

Comment: Dear newcomers, read the other answer with more upvotes before you are completely carried away by the counting game ...

Answer (score 12):

There is a difference between the two: something that consists of six things has exactly six things but something that contains six things may also contain other stuff.

As an example Coke contains sugar but consists of all the stuff listed as ingredients on the bottle.